# SelectionChanged event is not fired when selection is changed through code in ribbon dropdown

Tags: c#, excel, events

I have created an excel ribbon. It contains a button and a dropdown. The dropdown contains some items.

Now, in the SelectionChanged event of dropdown, I am displaying the label of selected item in MessageBox and it is getting displayed.

But when I am trying to change the index of dropdown on the button click, the selected item changes but the event is not fired.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Same thing works fine in Windows form application.

Here is the code:

```
    private void DD_SelectionChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DD.SelectedItem.Label);
    }

    private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        DD.SelectedItemIndex = 3;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just call DD_SelectionChanged directly from btnChange_Click.